# How to connect akka(java) with RDBMS

Tags: java, akka, rdbms, akka-persistence

I am new to Akka and want to create a CRUD application by using any RDBMS. I have gone through the akka-persistence which is quite confusing for me. But it lacks any implementation code.
Can anybody point me to the relative links/ git hub repository which will help in understanding.
Till now I have created a simple hello world application.

Comment: it is meant for Scala as per the link you provided. I am using java

Comment: Are you using https://github.com/dnvriend/akka-persistence-jdbc? I'm trying to find a java example with it - ideally to make this one https://github.com/akka/akka-samples/tree/2.5/akka-sample-persistence-java to work with PostgreSQL for example.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest to use [Slick](https://developer.lightbend.com/docs/alpakka/current/slick.html). There are several supported RDBMS connectors such as Postgres, Sql Server (Mssql), Mysql, Oracle, DB2. Previously I had to connect to an Oracle 12 database.

I added the dependency (in my case it was gradle) which can be found in docs.

```
"com.lightbend.akka:akka-stream-alpakka-slick_2.11:<version>",
```

After that I configured the slick as you can see below.

```
slick-oracle {
   profile = "slick.jdbc.OracleProfile$"
   db {
     dataSourceClass = "slick.jdbc.DriverDataSource"
     connectionPool = disabled
     properties {
       driver = "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
       url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/xe"
       user = user
       password = password
     }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Akka persistence allows you to persist the internal state of stateful actors in your system. Its rather convoluted to use it for CRUD applications, Instead you should start looking at a orm solution such as [slick](https://www.lightbend.com/community/core-tools/slick). You can use [akka-http](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/scala/http/) or [spray](http://spray.io/)(deprecated) to create a REST API that enables you to expose CRUD endpoints.